# [HTML]: Video tag with authentication

Tags: html, http, authentication, video

I need to play a video stream with HTTP auhtentication in a HTML page, like that:

```
<video src="username:password@path/to/video">
  <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>
```

My problem is that the credentials appears in HTML code. Anyone have an idea to hide it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a tokenization approach.  If you give each user a token, then only accept the token once, sharing no longer becomes a concern, and you maintain the privacy of your customers' information& password.

at [api.video](https://api.video), we offer the idea of a private video src=https://{videourl}?token={token}

If the server recognises the token, the video will play - only once.  Then subsequent attempts (say because the URL is shared) will fail. A new token can be generated for each legitimate view.